# How to print newline in rails view?

Tags: ruby, erb, ruby-on-rails-5

This is my `erb` :

```
<h1>Demo#hello</h1>
<p>This is my first Ruby on Rails Application :) </p>

<%= 1+2 %>

<% 10.times do %>
<%= "Hello,World\n" %>
<% end %>
```

which results in :

```
Demo#hello

This is my first Ruby on Rails Application :)
3 Hello,World Hello,World Hello,World Hello,World Hello,World Hello,World Hello,World Hello,World Hello,World Hello,World
```

I know...know there is some tag called `<br/>` which prints new line...
but I am curious if it could be done with "\n"....

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordinarily in HTML the newline character is treated as whitespace. But you can use CSS to break lines at newline characters:

```
white-space:pre-wrap;
```